# Matrix representation associated to a permutation representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I have just begun studying group representation theory.

I don't understand how  I can find the matrix representation associated to a permutation representation.
Should I identify each permutation with the corresponding permutation matrix?

Can you please recommend me some book about this argument (relation between matrix representation and permutation representation)?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Replace a permutation with the corresponding permutation matrix. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Can this be done for infinite groups; more specifically infnite Lie groups, meaning a matrix representation?